Конфликт React и react-redux
Я закончил проект, который без проблем запускается локально на компе. Но при попытке выгрузить его на Vercel получил вот такую ошибку:

Я пробовал по разному решить эту проблему. И с помощью --legacy-peer-deps и с --force. Постоянно идет конфликт версий между пакетами. Решив один конфликт, он порождает другой.
Вот еще скрин с терминала может это натолкнет вас на мысль как это решить:

Только теперь после удаления node_modules, через npm install не могу установить зависимости.
Если нужна будет ссылка на сам репозиторий дайте знать.

в package.json уберите у версий пакетов ^
